# Typescript compiler wont compile d.ts files [ Version 0.9.5 ]

Tags: typescript

I wanted to get started with some typescript but now I can't even compile one line of code.

Here is my code:

```
/// <reference path='jquery.d.ts' />

var test : String = "test";
```

When I try to run `tsc myFile.ts` I get 500 compile errors. 
Basically every line in the jquery.d.ts file is an error.

I used the most recent version of jquery from https://typescript.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#typings/jquery.d.ts

What is going on?

Comment: Actually you should get 'jquery.d.ts' from here: https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/jquery/jquery.d.ts

Comment: Your code works on the playground. My guess is that your .d.ts file contains invalid characters or something.

Comment: Thanks. I thought I checked that.

Comment: @BrunoLM that should be the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You have probably included the .ts file in you HTML file, but you should include the .js file. I've written a blog about common [Typescript](http://www.cloud-developer.eu/blog/2013/12/24/common-errors-issues-typescript-visual-studio/) mistakes.